# How To Invoke GetCurrentDirectory Method in Clojure CLR?

Tags: clojureclr

I am just trying out Clojure CLR a bit and I am stumped about how to make what seems as if it should be a pretty simple call work.

Version is Clojure 1.10.0-master-SNAPSHOT

In the REPL I do this:

```
(import 'System.IO.FileSystem)
(FileSystem/Directory/GetCurrentDirectory)
```

I get the following response:

```
Syntax error (InvalidOperationException) compiling at (REPL:1:2).
Unable to find static field: GetCurrentDirectory in
```

Everything I can find about "Unable to find static field:" would seem to indicate that I've got the assembly name wrong but that doesn't seem to be it.

I also tried this:

```
(. FileSystem/Directory GetCurrentDirectory)
```

and I get

```
Syntax error (InvalidOperationException) compiling at (REPL:1:2).
Unable to find static field: Directory in System.IO.FileSystem
```

Also tried this:

```
(FileSystem/Directory/GetCurrentDirectory [])
```

And I get this error:

```
Syntax error (InvalidOperationException) compiling at (REPL:1:2).
Unable to find static field: GetCurrentDirectory in
```

Can someone please tell me what it is that I've gotten wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under Core 3.1 and Net 5.0, `System.IO.FileSystem` does not contain `GetCurrenDirectory` or `Directory`.  (You can check this quickly by evaling `((map #(.Name %) (concat (.GetMethods System.IO.FileSystem) (.GetProperties System.IO.FileSystem))` to see what's available.)

There is a `System.IO.Directory` class with a `GetCurrentDirectory` method.  Try

```
(System.IO.Directory/GetCurrentDirectory)
```

or if you prefer to import the class

```
(import 'System.IO.Directory)
(Directory/GetCurrentDirectory)
```

Comment: I looked through MS documentation to see that I was getting that right; no doubt I was looking at the wrong version.